# Too much delay for indexing Sitemap in Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap

I know that Google don’t guarantee for indexing every single web page, but I need some clarification about that, because most of the SEO masters are saying

“*Submitting Sitemap in GWT is the most important task for indexing a page*”.

I had submitted my website’s site map before several months (may be years).

My sitemap contains 2253 web pages, out of that only 64 pages has been indexed so for. These 64 pages were indexed few months before itself which means, after those 64 pages Google hasn’t indexed even a single page.

What would be the reason?

[image]

Comment: Need some more info here. What type of pages are they and whats on them?  e,g. articles, products etc. Do they all have unique content, titles etc. Are you sure they aren't blocked else where, robots.txt, robots meta tags, etc. Have you manually checked if they are indexed? Also example URLs would be helpful.

Comment: They are product pages. I found that sitemap has been submitted on Crawl section as well as on robots.txt analysis.. see this image please : http://pho.to/2tPfe. Is it wrong?

Comment: Example URLS: http://www.proboxinggear.com/store/product_info.php?products_id=28 , http://www.proboxinggear.com/store/product_info.php?products_id=29 , http://www.proboxinggear.com/store/product_info.php?products_id=31 and so on.. i manually checked all urls and they are not indexed..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the incorrect URLs in your *sitemap.xml* files.  The URLs you list in the sitemap are actually being 301 redirected to different URLs.

e.g:

The link you posted:
http://www.proboxinggear.com/store/product_info.php?products_id=28

is 301 redirecting to:
http://www.proboxinggear.com/store/amber-heavybag-stand-with-adjustable-speedbag-platform-p-28.html

This is why Google is only reporting that a small amount of URLs listed are indexed. If you search for the redirected URLs they are indexed in Google:
[Example here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?num=100&site=&source=hp&q=%22http://www.proboxinggear.com/store/amber-heavybag-stand-with-adjustable-speedbag-platform-p-28.html%22&oq=%22http://www.proboxinggear.com/store/amber-heavybag-stand-with-adjustable-speedbag-platform-p-28.html%22&gs_l=hp.3...479.1428.0.1643.3.3.0.0.0.0.267.386.0j1j1.2.0...0.0.0..1c.1.17.hp.LQ4O5TyYHPI&pws=0)

You need to re-create your sitemap files and include **only live URLs, not redirected URLs.**

Also your *robots.txt* file is incorrect, you have missed out the user agent (as pointed out in the screen shot from Webmaster Tools).

It should look like:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /store-o

Sitemap: http://www.proboxinggear.com/store/sitemaps.xml
```

Comment: Thank you moobot.. does submitting site maps in robots.txt file as well as in crawl section (usual site map submitting area) is wrong?

Comment: No that's ok, you can do both.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your URLs clean first and then submit the sitemap including same URLs and try to put sitemap on root of website where `index.php` file is located , also use *robots.txt* to skip unwanted files or directories.